# Encrypt file AES-128-CBC

Tags: c#, encryption, openssl, aes, bouncycastle

I need your help to transcribe an OpenSSL command with the framework Bouncy Castle in C#.

The OpenSSL command is :

```
cms -encrypt -in e:\fichierBrut -binary -aes-128-cbc -outform der -out e:\ fichierBrut.pkcs7 e:\cnda.pem
```

The result with this command :

[image: Good File]

I want transcribe this command in C# with the framework :

```cs
byte[] contenu = File.ReadAllBytes("fichierBrut");

X509Certificate2 certificat = new X509Certificate2("cnda.cer");
Org.BouncyCastle.X509.X509Certificate cert = DotNetUtilities.FromX509Certificate(certificat);
CmsProcessableByteArray cmsByteArray2 = new CmsProcessableByteArray(contenu);

CmsEnvelopedDataGenerator envDataGen = new CmsEnvelopedDataGenerator();
envDataGen.AddKeyTransRecipient(cert);

CmsEnvelopedData enveloped = envDataGen.Generate(cmsByteArray2, "2.16.840.1.101.3.4.1.2");

File.WriteAllBytes("fichierBrut.pkcs7", enveloped.GetEncoded());
```

The result is :

[image]

I don’t have the same result with C#. The first part of file is the same, but the end is not the same. I need find out why my C# code doesn’t create the same result.